# Python Web Scraping Format Cleaning

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Still learning web scraping using python code with beautifulsoup and have stumbled across a formatting issue.

The code is pulling the correct data from the website, but it's not placing it in the proper columns.

For example:

Column `"unit_size"` should have ==> `5' x 8' x 10'`

But it's writing the dimensions every other row (along with other information that should be in the following columns).

Column `"unit_type"` should have ==> `"Drive Up 1st Floor Outside Level No Climate"`

Column `"online_price"` should have ==> `"$74.95"`

Column `"street_address"` should have ==> `1224 N Tryon St Charlotte NC 28206"`

You guys/girls are a great help.

Below is the python code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


urls = ['https://www.uhaul.com/Locations/Self-Storage-near-Charlotte-NC-28206/780052/'
    , 'https://www.uhaul.com/Locations/Self-Storage-near-Charlotte-NC-28212/780063/']


filename = "u_haul.csv"
open(filename, 'w').close()
f = open(filename, "a")
num = 0

headers = "unit_size, unit_type, online_price, street_address\n"

f.write(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


    street_address = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "address"}).text
    #store_city = page_soup.find("span", {"": ""}).text
    #store_postalcode = page_soup.find("span", {"": ""}).text     
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "row"})
    for container in containers:
        title_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "medium-4 medium-offset-2 small-7 columns"})
        unit_type = container.findAll("p", {"class": "collapse"})
        online_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "medium-3 column"})

        for item in zip(title_container, unit_type, online_price ):
            csv = item[0].text + "," + item[1].text + "," + item[2].text + "," + street_address + "\n"
            f.write(csv)
    num += 1

f.close()
```

Below is the HTML for containers:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <button class="pull-left toggle-trigger no-toggle-icon show-for-small-only" data-keep-events="" data-toggle-id="mainMenu" id="menuToggle">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>
        <!-- mp_trans_remove_start -->
        <button class="pull-right toggle-trigger no-toggle-icon show-for-small-only" data-keep-events="" data-toggle-id="searchBox" id="searchToggle">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
        <!-- mp_trans_remove_end  -->
        <a aria-label="Shopping Cart" class="pull-right button show-for-small-only" href="/Cart.aspx" id="header_cart_mobilie">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</a>
        <div class="logo">
            <a class="show-for-medium-up" href="/" id="header_logo_desktop">
<img alt="U-Haul" src="/Images/uhaul-logo.png?v=1290732713"/>
<img alt="Your moving and storage resource." src="/Images/uhaul_tagline.png?v=629728584"/>
</a>
            <a class="show-for-small-only" href="/" id="header_logo_mobile">
<img alt="U-Haul" src="/Images/uhaul_logo_white.png?v=291560867"/>
</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <ul class="inline text-right show-for-medium-up">
            <li>
                <a href="/Cart.aspx" id="header_cart">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    Cart
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Orders/" id="header_signinlookup">
<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                            Sign in / look up order
                        </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Locations/" id="header_locations">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    Locations
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the HTML for address:

```html
[ < div class = "address" >
    <
    p class = "collapse" >
    <
    span > 1224 N Tryon St < /span> <
    br / >
    <
    span > Charlotte < /span>, <
    span > NC < /span> <
    span > 28206 < /span><br/ >
    <
    /p>
```

Here is the HTML for the "unit_size" and "unit_type" columns:

```html
<div class="medium-4 medium-offset-2 small-7 columns">
    <h4 class="">
        5' x 8' x 10'
    </h4>
    <p class="collapse">
        Drive Up 1st Floor Outside Level No Climate <br/> Miscellaneous Storage (up to 2 rooms) <br/>
        <em></em>
    </p>
</div>
```

And finally below is the HTML for the "online_price" column:

```html
<div class="medium-3 column">
    <p>
        <strong class="text-large ">
                    $74.95
                </strong>
        <br/> per month
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: web browser doesn't care for spaces and tabs. It always display many spaces as one space - but you have to remove them using standard string functions like `strip()`, `split()`, `join()`, `replace()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browser doesn't care for spaces and tabs. It always display many spaces as one space - but you have to remove them using standard string functions like `strip()`, `split()`, `join()`, `replace()`, etc.

You should also use module `csv` because sometimes string may have `comma` (ie. street address) or `return/enter` and you have to put text in `" "` to correctly save in `CSV` file.
Module `csv` will do it automatically.

You can also chain functions `find`, `findAll`, `find_all`, `select`, `select_one`

```
page_soup.find('div', {'id': 'roomTypes'}).findAll("div", {"class": "row"})
```

Full code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

urls = [
    'https://www.uhaul.com/Locations/Self-Storage-near-Charlotte-NC-28206/780052/',
    'https://www.uhaul.com/Locations/Self-Storage-near-Charlotte-NC-28212/780063/'
]

filename = 'u_haul.csv'

f = open(filename, 'a+') # a+ will create file
csv_writer = csv.writer(f) # use csv module because some data may have comma or enter.

headers = ['title', 'unit_size', 'unit_type', 'online_price', 'street_address']
csv_writer.writerow(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')


    street_address = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "address"}).text

    street_address = ' '.join(street_address.split())
    print('street_address>', street_address, '<')
    print('---------------------------------------------------')

    #store_city = page_soup.find("span", {"": ""}).text
    #store_postalcode = page_soup.find("span", {"": ""}).text     

    containers = page_soup.find('div', {'id': 'roomTypes'}).findAll("div", {"class": "row"}) # <-- changed 

    for container in containers:
        title_container = container.find("div", {"class": "medium-4 medium-offset-2 small-7 columns"})
        unit_size = container.find("h4") # <-- changed 
        unit_type = container.find("p", {"class": "collapse"})
        online_price = container.find("strong", {"class": "text-large "}) # <-- changed 

        if title_container: # some rows doesn't have data 
            title = ' '.join(title_container.text.split())
            size = ' '.join(unit_size.text.split())
            unit = ' '.join(unit_type.text.split())
            price = online_price.text.strip()

            print('title>', title, '<')
            print('size>', size, '<')
            print('unit>', unit, '<')
            print('price>', price, '<')
            print('-----')

            csv_writer.writerow([title, size, unit, price, street_address])

f.close()
```

Result:

```
street_address> 1224 N Tryon St Charlotte, NC 28206 <
---------------------------------------------------
title> 5' x 8' x 10' Drive Up 1st Floor Outside Level No Climate Miscellaneous Storage (up to 2 rooms) <
size> 5' x 8' x 10' <
unit> Drive Up 1st Floor Outside Level No Climate Miscellaneous Storage (up to 2 rooms) <
price> $74.95 <
-----
title> 4' x 12' x 10' Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
size> 4' x 12' x 10' <
unit> Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
price> $79.95 <
-----
title> 5' x 10' x 10' Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
size> 5' x 10' x 10' <
unit> Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
price> $84.95 <
-----
title> 5' x 14' x 10' Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
size> 5' x 14' x 10' <
unit> Interior 1st Floor Street Level No Climate 1-2 Bedroom Home (up to 1,200 sq. ft.) <
price> $89.95 <
```

Comment: @ furas - Thank you, this fixed the issue. So how can I learn to use the standard string functions? For example, I would like to split the "unit_size" to show in column 1 (width) = 5, column 2 (length) = 8, column 3 (height) = 10. instead of having it show "5' x 8' x 10'". Same thing goes for "street_address", how can I change it to have the street in separate column from city and zipcode? Thank you again for you help.

Comment: `splitted_list = "5' x 8' x 10'".split(" x ")` and `splitted_list = street_address.split(",")`

Comment: maybe see [Learn X in Y minutes (Where X=python3)](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/)

Comment: or read in official documentation: [4.7.1. String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)